# Getx Storage return null whenever app starts

Tags: flutter, sharedpreferences, flutter-getx, flutter-state, flutter-sharedpreference

I have initilized GetStorage() in main() and calling .read() in onReady dunction of GetX Controller but always get null!

```
Future<void> main() async {
  await GetStorage.init();
  runApp(const App());
}
```

```
class AuthenticationRepository extends GetxController {
  static AuthenticationRepository get instance => Get.find();

  /// Variables
  GetStorage userStorage = GetStorage('User');

  @override
  void onReady() {
    // Firebase User
    firebaseUser = Rx<User?>(_auth.currentUser);
    firebaseUser.bindStream(_auth.userChanges());

    //Session
    print('========= BEFORE -- ${userStorage.read('isFirstTime')} ===========');
    userStorage.writeIfNull('isFirstTime', 'true');
    print('========= AFTER -- ${userStorage.read('isFirstTime')} ============');    
  }
```

**OUTPUT**

================== BEFORE -- null ========================
================== AFTER -- true =========================

I have tried named values also like GetStorage('User');
nothing worked.

Comment: Did you do Get.put(AuthenticationRepository())?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to give the container name in init if you are using a custom container name.

So, you have two solutions

**1** -> Update your init to this

```
Future<void> main() async {
  await GetStorage.init('User');  // <- add your custom Container name 'User'
  runApp(const App());
}
```

**OR**

**2** Don't use a custom container name and GetStorage uses it's default container name. In this case, update your code while declaring GetStorage object to read and write data

```
class AuthenticationRepository extends GetxController {
  static AuthenticationRepository get instance => Get.find();

  /// Variables
  GetStorage userStorage = GetStorage(); //<- remove custom container name 'User'

  @override
  void onReady() {
    // Firebase User
    firebaseUser = Rx<User?>(_auth.currentUser);
    firebaseUser.bindStream(_auth.userChanges());
//Session
print('========= BEFORE -- ${userStorage.read('isFirstTime')} ===========');
userStorage.writeIfNull('isFirstTime', 'true');
print('========= AFTER -- ${userStorage.read('isFirstTime')} ============');
```

}

Comment: Thank you both! Ali bhi it worked by removing the GetStorage('User');

Comment: One more question. Do i have to define all the custom containers if I want to use that approach?

Comment: No, defining a custom container is not necessary. it's additional functionality that Get Storage provides.

Answer (score 1):

Need  to add

> WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

---

```
Future<void> main() async {
      await GetStorage.init();
      runApp(const App());
    }
```

Change this to :

```
void main() async {
  await GetStorage.init();
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  runApp(const MyApp());
}
```

Comment: I have already added `WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();` I Don't know why but still not working.

Comment: Any other suggestion #Tasnuva Tavasum oshin

Comment: have you tried putting `GetStorage userStorage = GetStorage('User');` in onInit method?